# Website not "shrinking" to fit mobile devices

Tags: mobile, joomla2.5

I have a built plenty of websites and they all do the same thing on mobile devices. They shrink down all small like they're supposed to.

This website I built using Joomla 2.5 and the Wright Framework will not resize. (Yes I know Wright is a Bootstrap framework for Responsive Design but the client has requested in the end of the project for the website to NOT be responsive, they don't like it)

I have tried every  I can find. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's the website. View it on your mobile device and you'll see what I mean.

```
http://174.122.19.188/~rockwall/
```

Some meta name's I've tried:

```
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to "shrink" the page to the width of the screen, Set the viewport width to equal the width of your widest container.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 940">
```

If you want to allow the user to zoom in, add user-scalabel and set a maximum-scale.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=940, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Example [here](https://create.passkit.com)

Comment: It didn't work. Seems like it would, but it didn't. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a Responsive template and I turned it off. I may be way off.

Comment: Look in your template's CSS and comment our any media{} blocks.  This should completely disable the theme.

Comment: I went one step beyond. Just looking to see if I could get the website to fit. I deleted entire bootstrap.css files so I could see if there was a problem inside any of them. Nothing yet. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Use the following meta tag and it will work. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=970, maximum-scale=1.0">` - [Example here](http://dev.anatta.net/so.html)

Comment: I'm putting this in the <head>  on the template's main template.php. Is that not correct? I put it there and it's not working. But I have other meta information that is working there....so I assume it's the correct place to put it.

Comment: Get rid of any existing "viewport" tags and just use this one.

Comment: No you are not, if I look at your source I see two.  Remove this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` It is the initial-scale=1.0 that is causing the content to only show the top 320px x 640px

Comment: You are AWESOME! Thank you so much. I did an entire site search. It was in some include file that this specific Joomla template included.

Comment: Just checked your site on my iPhone, and it looks great - glad we got there and thks for accepting my answer